# Could a human run horizontally inside a Wall of Death?

Tags: centrifugal-force

A popular circus stunt is for a motorcycle rider to ride inside a bowl shaped depression called a "Wall of Death." The rider goes higher and higher up the wall until they are actually horizontal. I wonder if a human could do the same.

Answer (score 2):

The speed you need (explained http://physics.mut.ac.th/PhysicsMagic/wall.htm)

$$
V^2 > R g/u
$$

$v$ = the velocity (m/s)
$R$ = Radius of the pit (m)
$g$ = acceleration of gravity (9.8m/s^2)
$u$ = coeff of static friction

So if u is 1 (the maximum possible), and you are an olympic athlete that can run 100m in 10s
Then you apparently could with a radius of about 10m

$$
R = uV^2/g = 10^2/9.8 = 10m 
$$

Comment: How do you get that the maximum possible $\mu$ is $1$?

Comment: If $\mu$ were always less than one, a [conventional dragster](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2007/AnamAhmed.shtml) would be unable to accelerate at more than 1 g.

Comment: I believed only static friction exceeded 1. The dragster site proves me wrong.

Comment: what difference does it make that a runner is not in contact with the wall for a significant portion of the time while running? The frictional force would note be exerted on the runner during this time.

Comment: @luksen the runner is falling during the time they are not in contact with the ground and the downward momentum he picks up during that time has to be made up for during the time he IS in contact with the ground.  But the normal force for a runner's shoes is more than $mg$ anyway, so in the classical view of coefficient of friction the fact that some amount of time is spent off the ground is irrelevant.

Comment: Dragsters are not a good example, because both the tire and the track are intentionally prepared to be sticky. The standard Coulomb model of friction (the one with $\mu_s$ and $\mu_k$) doesn't work for wet or sticky surfaces. Also, some dragsters have wings, which provide a downward force, so even if the Coulomb model applied, you could have $a>\mu_s g$. Anyway, you can definitely have $\mu_s>1$. http://robotics.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ronf/Gecko/prl-friction.html

Comment: @Tim - Many thanks, I was typing it from my phone and couldn't get all the formating right.

Comment: I'd upvote if you'd fix the mistake about "the maximum possible."

Comment: @Ben - well obviously it's only valid for a smooth spherical non-relativistic athlete running in a vacuum

Comment: @Martin Beckett: I'm not objecting to your use of $\mu=1$ as an input to an order of magnitude estimate. That's a perfectly reasonable input for shoe soles on some kind of reasonable surface. I'm objecting to your description of it as "the maximum possible," which is simply wrong. Values as high as 2 are not unusual.

Comment: U=1 is the maximum possible for the conditions of a runner running with shoes on a normal surface. If the person had magnets, suction pads, glue, chemical bonds or some sort of mechanical cleat then you can have u>1. You can also get u>1 for two smooth surface that spot weld together but that's not really a useful definition of u.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer:  I found it easiest to approach this by asking the question in a different way --->  If a runner were to run around in circles on an inverted conical ramp, how fast would he have to run to remain perdendicular to the ramp's surface?  The answer depends on three things: radius for the running path; slope of the ramp (B) and height/mass distribution of the runner (shorter runners do better, since more of their mass is at a larger $v^2/R$).

Assumptions: 1.6m (5'3") tall runner, with a center of gravity (CoG) 0.8m from feet, on a 2m radius (approx 13 foot diameter) path.  Since he is tilted in from vertical, his CoG traces a path which has a diameter somewhat less than that: for now, estimate B = 40 degrees tilt, which give a path for the CoG of radius (2 - 0.8 sin(40))m = about 1.5m.

$a_d = 9.8 m/s^2$ is acceleration (due to gravity) straight down.  $a_L = V^2/R$ is acceleration laterally outward, due to centrifugal force.  $a_t$ is total acceleration, which will be perpendicular to ramp surface.

$a_d = a_tcos(B)$

$a_L = a_tsin(B)$

Therefore, we have $a_L = a_d tan(B)$ ----> $B = tan^{-1}(V^2/(R a_d)$

Remembering that the R in that equation is the R for CoG, and that the velocity of that CoG will be slower than speed of the runner's feet, we have...

$B = tan^{-1}((6.7 (m/s)(1.2/2))^2/(1.5(m) 9.8 (m/s^2))$ = about 47.8 degrees from horizontal.  Compare to the original guess of 40 degrees.  I'm not making a second iteration to correct path length: instead guess about 45 degrees.  This assumes that the runner is running a 4 minute mile, which is quite a feat to pull off on a conical ramp with path of radius 2 m, with your head (experiencing less centripetal force than CoG) constantly trying to fall in towards the center while your feet (experiencing more) trying to slide out from under you in the opposite direction.

Comment: Your calculation is incorrect. In the nonrotating frame, there is no centrifugal force, the acceleration is toward the center of the circle, not perpendicular to the surface, and it's inward, not outward. In the rotating frame, the acceleration is zero. You might want to start by drawing a free-body diagram, then applying Newton's second law.